# Saving Custom Registration Form Drupal 7 Using FAPI

Tags: 7, forms, users

Good Day.

I created a custom registration form in Drupal 7 using FAPI.

I managed to add validation and it works great. Now my problem is when saving it to the database. I can't save my custom data/fields(e.g first Name, Last Name, Birthday, etc) to my db. I don't know how to do it. I followed all the tuts here http://drupal.org/node/1063598 but it seems my blob data is 0 byte. Did i miss something wrong? here is my code. Any replies are much appreciated.

```
function drupal_onrevue1_form_user_register_submit($form, $form_state){


   $edit = array(
          'name' => $form_state['values']['name'], 
          'pass' => $form_state['values']['current_pass'],
          'field_first_name' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $form_state['values']['field_first_name']))),
          'field_last_name' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $form_state['values']['field_last_name']))),
          'field_middle_name' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $form_state['values']['field_middle_name']))),
          'field_year_select' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $form_state['values']['field_year_select']))),
          'field_month_select' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $form_state['values']['field_month_select']))),
          'field_date_select' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $form_state['values']['field_date_select']))),
          'field_gender_select' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $form_state['values']['field_gender_select']))),
          'mail' => $form_state['values']['field_mail'],
          'init' => $form_state['values']['field_mail'], 
          'status' => 1, 
          'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
    );
    user_save(drupal_anonymous_user(), $edit);
}

function form_user_register($form_state) {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'drupal_onrevue1_validate_register_form';
    $form['#submit'][] = 'drupal_onrevue1_form_user_register_submit';
    $month = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October','November', 'December');
    for($i=1; $i < 32; $i++){
        $date[] = $i;
    }

    for($i=date("Y"); $i > 1900; $i--){
        $year[] = $i;
    }


    $form['field_first_name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('reg_input _con'), 'placeholder' =>'First Name'),
    );
    $form['field_last_name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('reg_input _con'), 'placeholder' =>'Last Name'),
    );
    $form['field_middle_name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#maxlength' => '2',
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('reg_input1 _con'), 'placeholder' =>'M.I'),
    );

    $form['field_gender_select'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('drop_filed')),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#empty_option' => '- Gender -',
        '#options' => array(
            1 => t('Male'),
            2 => t('Female'),
        ),
    );

    $form['field_month_select'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('drop_filed _con')),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#empty_option' => '- Month -',
        '#options' => $month,
    );

    $form['field_date_select'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#empty_option' => '- Date -',
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('drop_filed1 _con'), 'style'=>'width:70px;'),
        '#options' => $date
    );

    $form['field_year_select'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#empty_option' => '- Year -',
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('drop_filed1'), 'style'=>'width:80px;'),
        '#options' => $year,

    );


    $form['field_mail'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('reg_input _3 '), 'placeholder' =>'Email Address'),
    );

    $form['name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('reg_input _3'), 'placeholder' =>'Username')
    );

    $form['current_pass'] = array(
        '#type' => 'password',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('reg_input _3 '), 'placeholder' =>'Password'),
    );

    $form['field_repassword'] = array(
        '#type' => 'password',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('reg_input _3 '), 'placeholder' =>'Re-type Password'),
    );

    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
        '#attributes' =>  array('class' => array("btn btn-medium btn-success"), 'style'=>'width:60px'), 
    );  

    return $form;   
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

use &$form_state instead of $form_state in function name
it should be

```
 function drupal_onrevue1_form_user_register_submit($form, &$form_state)
```

U have stated blob data as 0 byte. Are the other fields getting stored or not?
 for viewing values in submit use drupal_set_message() to check the values at runtime.

Comment: Not working...

yes...my data is 0 byte in table user...other fields has been stored like the mail, username, pass, status...but other than that it can't save...my question where should first_name, last_name, middle_name, etc. will be saved? at the data fields? or anywhere?? Thanks

Comment: It will be saved at data fields... check the table whether the names of fields are same as you have given in your code.... if other fields like mail,username are getting stored it means values are there in submit function

Comment: yeah....I can save the username,password, status...

But the first_name, last_name, etc...can't save to the data field (blob is in 0 byte)

Comment: If i am not mistaken....other custom fields (e.g fist_name, last_name, middle_name) will be serialized and save to the data column right?

Comment: fields have to be serialized....

Comment: can you please tell me how to do it at my code?? in my submit function??